# embedded python in c++, do i need python installed

Tags: c++, python, static-linking, python-embedding

when embedding python in a c++ application using

```
#include "python2.6/Python.h"
```

and linking -lpython2.6

does the target computer (computer running the final compiled program) need to have python installed in order to work with my application?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Are you linking the libraries statically or dynamically?
If you link dynamically then yes your target computer needs to have Python installed.

Comment: Statically or dynamically linking is not important, since you can't link Python statically. You could link the interpreter and language core statically, but then you'd still need a bunch of Python modules for full functionality, effectively making it impossible to link the whole statically.